# What is wrong with my siamese network? Why does it output the same value(appx 0.5) irrespective of the input pairs?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, siamese-network

I'm trying to build a Siamese Network for https://www.kaggle.com/moltean/fruits dataset. I've picked 10 Images per class from this dataset. There are a total of 131 classes in this dataset. I'm using the below model to train my network. However, it is failing to converge. I saw a strange behaviour, after 3000 epochs my results are 0.5000003 irrespective of the input pair I give and my loss stops at 0.61. The specifications of the network are as specified in the [paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ersalakhu/papers/oneshot1.pdf). I tried changing the following things,

1. Changing Denes layer activation to ReLU
2. Importing 'ImageNet' weights of ResNet50
3. Tried increasing and decreasing learning rate.

I also checked the batch inputs to see if the correct input pair (x) is paired with the correct y value. However, I think I'm doing something basically wrong. Glad if you could help me. Thank you :)

The notebook is hosted in Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/krishnaprasad96/siamese-network.
If you have some doubts on how certain parts of the code works refer https://medium.com/@krishnaprasad_54871/siamese-networks-line-by-line-explanation-for-beginners-55b8be1d2fc6

```
#Building a sequential model
input_shape=(100, 100, 3)
left_input = Input(input_shape)
right_input = Input(input_shape)

W_init = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean = 0.0, stddev = 1e-2)
b_init = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean = 0.5, stddev = 1e-2)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (10,10), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, kernel_initializer=W_init, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (7,7), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=W_init, bias_initializer=b_init, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=W_init, bias_initializer=b_init, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=W_init, bias_initializer=b_init, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=W_init, bias_initializer=b_init, kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-3))
])

encoded_l = model(left_input)
encoded_r = model(right_input)

subtracted = keras.layers.Subtract()([encoded_l, encoded_r])
prediction = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', bias_initializer=b_init)(subtracted)
siamese_net = Model(input=[left_input, right_input], output=prediction)

optimizer= Adam(learning_rate=0.0006)
siamese_net.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)

plot_model(siamese_net, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

Comment: Please do not use conversational stuff in the title (edited)

Comment: @desertnaut Ohh cool! I have changed it. Do you know the reason why this is happening by any chance?

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for machine learning stack exchange, and borderline off topic for stack exchange. You have not in your question formulated a question about programming - rather it is a question about debugging nerual networks.

Answer (score 1):

**Siamese Neural Networks** are notoriously difficult to train. What you are essentially doing is carefully teaching the model how to tell 2 things apart.

To do that you cannot show the model every sample class in training as the model will just learn that sample class's characteristics. So Teaching the mode to learn to How tell things apart needs a test set that has classes never before seen by the model. Hence the different classes.
*Responding to the previous Answer.*

Back to the Main Point. The issue with **OP's** Question is that the model was designed for classification and not similarity learning. You Might get a High accuracy but that is just because binary_crossentropy loss has a default threshold of 0.5.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the architecture. *It was just designed for something else.* You are better off using a **pre-trained model** as a feature extractor and applying a **contrastive loss** at the end and not creating one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the notebook on kaggle. Thanks for all the information. But it seems that training and validation spilt is wrong. As this model trains on initial 91 classes only. What about remaining 40 classes. Train and validation spilt should be from the same class. Suppose I have 10 images in a class. I can use 8 image for train and 2 images for validation. Train and validation spilt should be on images not on classes. Also I couldn't see the testing script. It would be a great help if you can provide that also.

Comment: Since this is not a complete answer, I think it would be better suited as a comment or two.